# Incompatibility between ListView, RelativeLayout and onMeasure

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

My app uses a ListView with the following layout for each list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.myapp.Square
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Square is a custom View with an overridden `onMeasure()`, to allow it to fill the smaller dimension of the screen while remaining square, in cases where the dimensions are set to `match_parent`.  This functionality is not needed in the ListView but it is used elsewhere in the app.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int w, int h) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        super.onMeasure(h, h);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(w, w);
    }
}
```

The result is that the square has zero size, in landscape only (i.e. when the height is used as the width).  The problem goes away in the following cases:

- when LinearLayout is used instead of RelativeLayout
- when the onMeasure is removed, or
- when the ListView is removed (i.e. the list item layout is used as the layout for the entire activity)

As you can see, it's a very specific case.

My guess is that the problem has to do with the height of a ListView element being treated differently than the width, because ListView elements are forced to match their content's height.  However, since the height of the content is specified explicitly here, there should be no problem; and in any case, this doesn't explain the different behaviour between LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.

There are straight-forward work-arounds to the problem (e.g. not using the custom `onMeasure()` for squares inside ListViews) but I'd like to better understand the problem.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int w, int h) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        super.onMeasure(h, h);
setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(h), MeasureSpec.getSize(h));
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(w, w);
setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(w), MeasureSpec.getSize(w));
    }
}
```